# Strange Behaviour of the assignment operator

Tags: c++, xcode, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I have a class as follows :

```
class Point {
public:
    Point() { cout << "\nDefault Constructor called"; }
    Point(const Point &t) { cout << "\nCopy constructor called"; }
};
```

and in someFunction() I am trying

```
void someFunction()
{
    Point *t1, *t2;
    t1 = new Point();
    t2 = new Point(*t1);
    Point t3 = *t1;
    Point t4;
    t4 = t3;
    t4 = *t1;
    t4 = t3;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the last three lines of code is not getting executed. Even when I am debugging on Xcode control flows directly from `Point t4;`
to end of the code.
why constructor not being called here as it is being call for `Point t3 = *t1;`

Comment: Constructors are used for constructing new objects, not for assigning new values to existing ones.

Comment: Just a bit of terminology: a constructor that can be called with no arguments is a **default constructor**, not a "normal" constructor.

Comment: @PeteBecker - updated Normal to Default. My apologies for wrong name.

Comment: @Aisha -- no need to apologize. There's a lot of terminology, and it's easy to get confused when you're getting started.

Answer (score 2):

`t4 = t3;` is assignment, not initialization. You need the assignment operator `Point & operator=(const Point&t)` to see an output, otherwise it would use the default assignment operator, which does nothing in your case:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Point {
public:
    Point() { cout << "\nNormal Constructor called"; }
    Point(const Point &t) { cout << "\nCopy constructor called"; }
    Point & operator=(const Point&t) { cout << "\nAssignment"; return *this;}
};
int main() {
    Point *t1, *t2;
    t1 = new Point();
    t2 = new Point(*t1);
    Point t3 = *t1;
    Point t4;
    t4 = t3;
    t4 = *t1;
    t4 = t3;
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
Normal Constructor called
Copy constructor called
Copy constructor called
Normal Constructor called
Assignment
Assignment
Assignment
```

https://ideone.com/Za6lkL

Answer (score 2):

Copy constructor and assignment are two different things. `'t4 = t3;'` is an assignment, not initialization. Add

```
Point& operator = (const Point &t) { cout << "\nAssignment called"; return *this;}
```

in your class and you will see they are being called.

***Debugging on Xcode control flows directly from Point t4; to end of the code.***

This is because there is nothing to debug in these line of code. Add the above code then you can see control flow through these lines as well.

*Further, As suggested by @Craig Young*

Any decent optimizer would remove those 3 lines because they have zero effect of the overall behaviour. Do something with `t4` after each assignment (e.g. Give Point an `x` member and call `std::cout << t4.x;`) then the assignment cannot be so trivially removed by the optimizer. And you will see control flow through these lines as well.

Comment: @CraigYoung - Why will these assignments be eliminated ?

Comment: @CraigYoung are you suggesting to add optimiser  related behaviour  in answer ?

Comment: Rizwan : Your assignment operator is non-canonical. It should return a reference to the Point. It should behave the same was an int types. I should be able to do `Point p5, p6, p7; p5 = p6 = p7;` and I can't.

Comment: Craig Young: Even if a manual  assignment operator is not supplied, the compiler generated one will be called even if inlined insitu. I don't care if the assignment operator  can no longer be optimised out, only that it is canonical.

Comment: @SJHowe you mean     Point& operator = (const Point &t) { cout << "\nAssignment called"; return *this;}

Comment: Rizwan: Yes. That is better.